# Using multiple controllers defined via module does not work

Tags: angularjs

When defining controllers as global functions, everything works fine. But when using the modules to declare and "assign" the controllers, only the first controller is used to resolve the bindings. What am i missing?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head/>
<body>
  <div ng-app="flintstones">
    <div ng-controller="flintstoneCtrl">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-app="rumbles">
    <div ng-controller="rumbleCtrl">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var flintstones = angular.module("flintstones", []);
  flintstones.controller("flintstoneCtrl", function flintstoneCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.yourName = "Fred";
  });

  var rumbles = angular.module("rumbles", []);
  rumbles.controller("rumbleCtrl", function rumbleCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.yourName = "Barney";
  });

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I think, one page can have only one `ng-app` in your case you have two `ng-app` definitions, if you have multiple apps in a page you have to do manual bootstrapping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, one page can have only one `ng-app` as default, in your case you have two `ng-app` definitions.

[If you have multiple apps in a page you have to do manual bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860595/how-to-define-two-angular-apps-modules-in-one-page)

Answer (score 12):

@Arun is correct. However, in your case I'm guessing you don't really want to bootstrap Angular twice, but simply use controllers defined in different modules.

This is usually done by having a page/site module which have dependencies on all modules required, in your case `flintstones` and `rumbles`.

```
angular.module('flintstones', []).controller('flintstoneCtrl', ...);
angular.module('rumbles', []).controller('rumbleCtrl', ...);

// Create a module with dependencies.
angular.module('myApp', ['flintstones', 'rumbles'])...
```

In your html, you then simply use `ng-app="myApp"` and content from that module and all its dependencies will be accessible.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="flintstoneCtrl">...</div>
    <div ng-controller="rumbleCtrl">...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the addition. But actually i really need to bootstrap each module manually, since i can't know which component is used at runtime. It's for a quite big WCMS project and in some pages/contexts, i know the set of components (where i would choose your approach), in some pages/contexts that doesn't work so i really have to bootstrap everything by hand.