# AngularJS - multiple $http request for a single page

Tags: angularjs

I am devloping a single web page with angularJS. The page should display contents from another services which will return values as JSON.

I am using like below,

**View file:**

```
<div ng-app="phonecat">
   <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<div ng-app="tabletcat">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

**app js file**

```
angular.module('phonecat', []).
   config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
      when('', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',   controller: PhoneListCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/phones'});
}]);

angular.module('tabletcat', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
      when('', {templateUrl: 'partials/tablet-list.html',   controller: TabListCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/phones'});
 }]);
```

it displays the phone list properly. But it is not triggering the tablet list.

Suggest me the best practice to achieve this.

Comment: multiple ng-view are not allowed

Comment: You have to manually bootrstrap both apps. I had the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080113/using-multiple-controllers-defined-via-module-does-not-work

Answer (score 3):

You can't use multiple ngApp directives in the same document, as mentioned by [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angApp) :

> ngApp (directive in module ng )
>   Use this directive to auto-bootstrap an application. Only one directive can be used per HTML document.

You probably wanted rather have multiple [controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angController) ?

Comment: YES. I want to have multiple controller. Can you please guide me how to acheive it?

Answer (score 0):

Given the markup:

```
<div id="phonecatElement">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<div id="tabletcatElement">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Use the following

```
angular.bootstrap($('#phonecatElement'), ["phonecat"]);
angular.bootstrap($('#tabletcatElement'), ["tabletcat"]);
```