# How to make AngularJS route works with index.html/#/myPage like index.html#/myPage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, angular-ui-router

my current iFrame page is loaded with a **index.html#/myPage** it works nicely under Chrome or Safari, but not with IE **11**

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325539/angular-js-iframes-and-firefox) on SO : 
add a / before the # (**index.html/#/myPage**) and it will solve your problem

it looks so simple, but in my case it produces a **404 Page not found**

it seems that my route provider doesn't support the / before the #, why ?

Routing code :

```
appSkeleton.config(
    function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                template: '<skeleton-manage></skeleton-manage>'
            })
            .when('/skeletonManage', {
                template: '<skeleton-display-and-manage></skeleton-display-and-manage>'
            })
           .when('/employeeManage/:employeeId/:displayMode/:idItemClick?', {
                template: '<employee-display-and-manage></employee-display-and-manage>'
            })          
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo:'/'
            });

    }
);
```

The application works on a **Node.JS** server

Comment: Because whatever web server you are using is treating `/index.html/` as _not_ the same resource as `/index.html`. That's _normal_. You can change this behavior at the web server level using some sort of aliases or URL rewriting. Depends on what's serving that resource.

Comment: can you show us your routing code? and which version of IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It didn't work with app/index.html#/ but It worked well with app/#/, you don't need specify the index.html on URL
or you can redirect directly to URL without index.html by code

```
var url =  window.location.href;
      if(url.indexOf("index.html") > 0){
          window.location.replace(url.replace("index.html",""));
}
```