# Iframe not working with angularjs route in IE and firefox

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe, angular-ui-router

I am using iframe with angularjs route. The url which I am providing to iframe is an angular route.

```
$scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://localhost:3000/#/abc/param1/param2')
```

Here is the iframe.

```
 <iframe ng-src="{{url}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

It is working fine in Chrome but it doesn't show in IE or firefox. I tried providing url as '/#/abc/param1/param2' but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I tried giving controller name but it doesn't work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495826/angular-js-iframe-not-working-in-firefox-and-ie-11

Comment: I tried embedding the angular route page in other page, it worked for me, but when I tried to embed the angular route page inside angular route it didnt work.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure Did you find any solution?