# Html using # for iframe paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

I have an angular app with routing where different paths look like
`example.com/#/route1`, `example.com/#/route2`, etc.

When using links within the same page, it does not cause a reload of the page. I intend to support multiple apps like this by allowing them to run inside an iframe while I handle the navigation.

Currently, I am changing the path in the iframe as follows using jquery:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/#/route1">
<iframe src="http://example.com/#/route2">
```

But changing from one to the other causes the page inside the iframe to refresh.

Any ideas on how to achieve the routing without a reload?
Thanks.

Edit: ex. if you enter one path in your browser and then enter the second one, the page does not reload. I would like to achieve this same functionality but instead of changing the path in the browser, changing it in the iframe.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `iframes` and not Angular templates?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean, you want to switch between URL's without a page reload?

Comment: Yes, when you switch between those urls from the regular page it does not cause a page reload. Ex if you enter one path in your browser and then enter the second one, the page does not reload. I would like to achieve this same functionality but instead of changing the path in the browser, changing it in the iframe.

Comment: You might want to look here for an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725811/multiple-angularjs-applications-driving-portlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of the iframe does not reload the page, it behaves just like the browser. I had a logic error in my code that made it refresh.
Thanks again for all the comments.