# Two modules on single page not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js . I have two modules first2a,first22. Each modules have one controller model1 and model2.

Below is my Html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
        <head>
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="globe/images/correct.png"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="globe/css/style.css"/>     
            <script type="text/javascript" src="globe/script/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="globe/script/angular.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="globe/script/mainscope1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="globe/script/angular-route.js"></script>
            <title>
                Html5 All in One
            </title>
        </head>
        <body >
            <!-- MAin page -->
                <div  ng-app="first22" id="maincontainer" > 
                        <div ng-controller="model1">{{message}}</div>
                </div>
            <!-- MAin page End-->   
            <!-- Interactivity page -->     
                <div id="Interactive_content" ng-app="firsta" >
                    <div ng-controller="model2">{{message}}</div>
                </div>
            <!-- Interactivity page End-->          
        </body>
    </html>
```

mainscope1.js

```
var first2 = angular.module('first22', []);

    first2.controller('model1',function($scope)
    {
        $scope.message="aaaaaaa";

    })

var first2a=angular.module('firsta',[]);

    first2a.controller('model2',function($scope)
    {
        $scope.message="aaaaaaa1";

    })
```

Can anyone explain why firsta module is not working here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using angular boostrap , to happen when the document is ready:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() { 
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('maincontainer'), ['first22']);
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('Interactive_content'), ['firsta']);
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9sYB/59/)

Comment: could you please provide me the fiddle it would be usefull for me to understand

Comment: @user3792784 i have added fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can only use ng-app once per page. Are you trying to create two separate web applications side by side on this page, or are you only trying to have two controllers within a single application?

If you really want them to be a single application (which is what you normally would want), you set ng-app so that both ng-controller directives are inside it. For example, you can set ng-app on the html-tag, the body-tag or a div that wraps it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
        <head>
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="globe/images/correct.png"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="globe/css/style.css"/>     
            <script type="text/javascript" src="globe/script/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="globe/script/angular.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="globe/script/mainscope1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="globe/script/angular-route.js"></script>
            <title>
                Html5 All in One
            </title>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="myAngularApplication">
            <!-- MAin page -->
                <div id="maincontainer" > 
                        <div ng-controller="model1">{{message}}</div>
                </div>
            <!-- MAin page End-->   
            <!-- Interactivity page -->     
                <div id="Interactive_content" >
                    <div ng-controller="model2">{{message}}</div>
                </div>
            <!-- Interactivity page End-->          
        </body>
    </html>
```

And the javascript would be:

```
var first2 = angular.module('myAngularApplication', []);

    first2.controller('model1',function($scope)
    {
        $scope.message="aaaaaaa";

    });

    first2.controller('model2',function($scope)
    {
        $scope.message="aaaaaaa1";

    });
```

**OR**, if you want to create two fully separated applications on the same page, you need to bootstrap them manually without using ng-app. Please see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page) for details on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12864137/1177295

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define
>   the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple
>   applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them
>   using angular.bootstrap instead. AngularJS applications cannot be
>   nested within each other. --
>   http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp