# Confusion about data usage in Controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

How can I use the fetched data in `customersController` in `AnotherCustomersController`

```
function customersController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
}

function AnotherCustomersController($scope){ 
  //What should I do here??
}
```

[Full Details Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JjwZ9xKcyKvvOdwRAHYG?p=preview)

Comment: You need to post the code

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12233991/1223357
Abstract logic responsible for fetching data to reusable service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share data between controllers using [$rootscope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18881189/1223357) but I don't think this is a best practice so my solution contain usage of angular service -> [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pBtN3i6vJ5qsV9nztDJi?p=preview)

```
app.factory('CustomerService', function ($http) {
  return {
    fetchData: function () {
      return $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php')
    }
  }
});

app.controller('customersController', function ($scope, CustomerService) {

  CustomerService.fetchData().success(function (response) {
    $scope.names = response;
  });

});

app.controller('AnotherCustomersController', function ($scope, CustomerService) {

  CustomerService.fetchData().success(function (response) {
    $scope.names = response;
  });

});
```

Additionally i have refactor your code so only **one app** is used on page. If you want to use more than one you have to bootstrap them manually -> [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860595/how-to-define-two-angular-apps-modules-in-one-page)