# Nested App inside controller in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how can I achieve that structure in AnglularJS ?

```
<body ng-app="mainBodyAppWrapper">
        <div ng-controller = "mainBodyController">
            <div ng-app="myApp">
                <div ng-controller="controller3">
                    First Name : <input ng-model="myApp_fName3" type="text"/>
                    Last Name : <input ng-model="myApp_lName3" type="text"/>
                    Hello {{myApp_fName3}} {{myApp_lName3}} !!!
                </div>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

in that case I have an error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=controller3&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

Any one know about that kind of error solution? Please help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define two angular apps / modules in one page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860595/how-to-define-two-angular-apps-modules-in-one-page)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use multiple ng-app in a page. If you really need to use multiple modules, consider bootstraping the second module. For more info, read [How to define two angular apps / modules in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860595/how-to-define-two-angular-apps-modules-in-one-page)