# Angular Subsequent Modules Working

Tags: angularjs

In this example why isn't the 2nd module working?

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/19999/).

HTML

```
<div ng-app="My.App" ng-controller="MyController">
    Hello {{ test }}
</div>

<div ng-app="My.App2" ng-controller="MyController2">
    Hello {{ test2 }}
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var MyApp = angular.module("My.App", []);
var MyApp2 = angular.module("My.App2", []);

MyApp.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
      $scope.test = "Bob";
});

MyApp2.controller("MyController2", function($scope) {
      $scope.test2 = "Bob";
});
```

Result

> Hello Bob
>
> Hello {{ test2 }}

Comment: are you sure this is the correct JSFiddle? Because it's not the same as the code in your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define two angular apps / modules in one page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860595/how-to-define-two-angular-apps-modules-in-one-page)

Comment: I've corrected the Fiddle link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. You can only have one `ngApp` directive in one HTML document.

See respective docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Edit: 
There is another way as mentioned below - where you bootstrap the second module manually with `angular.bootstrap`, see:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

I have updated your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20000/

Comment: You can have multiple ngApp directives in one HTML page but  only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped.

Comment: Sorry I missed that - I will add this info to my answer. Thank you for the hint.