# Nest/Share Angular applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 list of items say, news and people.

These 2 lists have different logic and are located in different pages, so don't share shame `ng-app`:

```
<!-- News.html -->
<div id="newsList" ng-app="newsListApp">
   <div id="{{news.id}}" ng-app="modalApp" ng-repeat="news in newsList">
      ...
   </div>
</div>

<!-- People.html -->    
<div id="peopleList" ng-app="peopleListApp">
   <div id="{{person.id}}" ng-app="modalApp" ng-repeat="person in people">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to open each item in a modal popup, so I have to use a `modalApp`, but I want to use **the same `modalApp`**(that will use *the same* popup template) in the `news` and `people` lists...

What is the concept of sharing angular application/modules in cases like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it using `ng-app`.  You have to manually bootstrap at least one of them.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860595/how-to-define-two-angular-apps-modules-in-one-page) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing up `ng-app` and `ng-controller`. Probably you are looking for something like this. In general angular only expects one app per page, and they certainly shouldn't be nested

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="newsList" ng-controller="newsListCtrl">
    <div id="{{news.id}}" ng-controller="modalCtrl" ng-repeat="news in newsList">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="peopleList" ng-controller="peopleListCtrl">
    <div id="{{person.id}}" ng-controller="modalCtrl" ng-repeat="person in people">
       ...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

**Edit:**
If `news` and `people` are different pages then you need a router of some kind. Your main options are [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). I think ui-router is more flexible to I would go with that. Couple of useful links that might help out:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router
http://plnkr.co/edit/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg?p=preview

Comment: forgot to mention that news and people are 2 different pages... and share different logic, so aren't part of same myApp

Comment: Could you explain a little how should I link routers with the shared "ng-application"...?

Comment: Just follow the plnkr link above. Basically you need a single view per page. A view comprises an html template and a controller. Look at script.js in the plunkr link for how the controller and templates are linked together.