# Why run method of this module isn't run?

Tags: angularjs, angular-module

In following example there are three modules, first one is required by second module. And this works when referenced using `ng-app` in `div`. But third module that goes by the name of `someonesApp` does not work. It's run method is not run when second module is being referenced using ng-app. Without first two modules third one works, why is that so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-init="name='123'">

<div ng-app="myApp">
</div>

<div ng-app="someonesApp">
</div>



<script>

var yourApp = angular.module('yourApp',[]);
yourApp.run(function(){
    console.log('run block of yourApp');
});


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['yourApp']);

myApp.run(function(){
    console.log('run block of myApp');
});


var someonesApp = angular.module('someonesApp',[]);

someonesApp.run(function(){
    console.log('run block of someonesApp');
});



</script>

</body>    
</html>
```

Here is modified code, in this case I removed `<div ng-app="myApp"></div>` and third module works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-init="name='123'">

<div ng-app="someonesApp">
</div>



<script>

var yourApp = angular.module('yourApp',[]);
yourApp.run(function(){
    console.log('run block of yourApp');
});


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['yourApp']);

myApp.run(function(){
    console.log('run block of myApp');
});


var someonesApp = angular.module('someonesApp',[]);

someonesApp.run(function(){
    console.log('run block of someonesApp');
});



</script>

</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Problem has been solved, this was the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12864137/4913383

Comment: Then delete this question.