# Why my Angular factory throw TypeError: __tracer.traceFunCall(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This line of code does no let me sleep:

```
$scope.search = function (login) {
      github.getUser(login).then(onUserResponse, onError);
    };
```

Loading it up:

```
angular.module('lol')
    .factory('github', github);
```

Returning two functions :

```
return {
      getUser: getUser,
      getRepos: getRepos
    };
```

With this siganture:

```
var github = function ($http) {
```

Consumed by MainController:

```
  var MainCtrl = function ($scope, github, $filter, $timeout, $intervel, $anchorScroll, $location) {
```

And not injected into it's dependencies:

```
 MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter', '$interval', '$timeout', '$anchorScroll', '$location'];
```

With the app being loaded like this:

```
angular.module('lol', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
```

And all of this throw: `TypeError: __tracer.traceFunCall(...) is not a function`

Comment: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mifukibugu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed `github`as second parameter in `MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'github'...`
also updated your jsbin [here](https://jsbin.com/puyaqatiye/1/edit?html,js,console,output)
code organization was complicating situation more than necesary.
Also from the looks of it you tried to do two modules quick example how it should be done [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28193298/1278129)

Comment: Then I get an error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: v0Provider <- v0 <- github`

Comment: just paste your code m8 in jsbin or plunker and share link, cause now it's too many if's. From the looks of error angular can't find `github` factory.