# How to call a module multiple times?

Tags: angularjs

`startupModule.js`:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    let app = angular.module('startupModule', []);

    app.controller('controller1', function () {
        // do this work on loading...
    });

    app.controller('controller2', function () {
        // do this work on loading...    
    });
}());
```

`loginModule.js`:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    let app = angular.module('loginModule', []);

    app.controller('loginController', function () {

    });
}());
```

In the view:

```
<div ng-app="startupModule" ng-controller="controller1">

</div>

<div ng-app="loginModule" ng-controller="loginController">

</div>

<div ng-app="startupModule" ng-controller="controller2">

</div>
```

On loading, I want to call controllers `controller1` and `controller2` to do some works automatically. `loginModule` is the main module that I want to use and it cannot be removed or combined with `startupModule`.

When I run it, there was no error in `Console`. But the controller `controller2` in the third div cannot be excuted, because `ng-app="startupModule"` cannot be recalled (I guess).

To check again, I've removed `ng-app="startupController" ng-controller="controller1"` in the first div. Then, `controller2` should work.

My question: how can I call a module via calling `ng-app` multiple times?

Comment: You can only have one `ng-app` directive which bootstraps automatically. If you have multiple modules, you'll have to bootstrap them yourself. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12864137/3153169) for reference

Comment: Check [ngApp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp). Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document (using `ng-app`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [AngularJs docs for `ngApp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp),

> only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using `angular.bootstrap` instead.

So, you have to bootstrap your modules manually. For example:

```
<div id="app1" ng-controller="controller1"></div>    
<div id="app2" ng-controller="loginController"></div>    
<div id="app3" ng-controller="controller2"></div>
```

So that from javascript you can bootstrap them:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var 
        app1 = document.getElementById('app1'),
        app2 = document.getElementById('app2'),
        app3 = document.getElementById('app3');

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(app1 , ['startupModule']);
        angular.bootstrap(app2 , ['loginModule']);
        angular.bootstrap(app3 , ['startupModule']);
    });
})();
```