# Pass Service As A Controller Parameter

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I've a `AngularJs` controller that gets a list of categories from `ASP.NET MVC` controller. It works just fine and here is the below code:

```
productApp.controller('categoryController', function ($scope, categoryService) { //The controller here
    $scope.Categories = null;

    categoryService.GetCategories().then(function (d) {
        $scope.Categories = d.data;

    }, function () {
        alert('Failed');
    });
});

productApp.factory('categoryService', function ($http) { //The product service
    var factory = {};

    factory.GetCategories = function () {
        return $http.get('/Product/GetCategories'); //The ASP.NET MVC controlled defined
    }
    return factory;
});
```

I am trying to convert it to the following passing the service as a controller parameter but it doesn't work:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('productApp', ['ngMessages'])
        .controller('categoryController', categoryController);

    categoryController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Products'];

    function categoryController($scope, categoryService) {
            $scope.Categories = null;

            categoryService.GetCategories().then(function (d) {
                $scope.Categories = d.data;

            }, function () {
                alert('Failed');
            });
    }

    productApp.factory('categoryService', function ($http) { //The product service
        var factory = {};

        factory.GetCategories = function () {
            return $http.get('/Product/GetCategories'); //The ASP.NET MVC controlled defined
        }
        return factory;
    });
})();
```

My requirement is to get all the controller united as follows:

```
angular
    .module('productApp')
    .controller('categoryController', categoryController)
    .controller('productController', productController);
```

I believe, I am close enough and missing something here. I would expect some suggestions to implement it in the correct way. Thanks.

**Update 1 -** The below code works almost but it doesn't bind the `DropDownList` with category data: But using alert method, it returns **[Object][Object]** that means it gets categories from database

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('productApp', [])
        .controller('categoryController', categoryController)
        .factory('categoryService', categoryService);

    categoryController.$inject = ['$scope', 'categoryService'];

    function categoryController($scope, categoryService) {
        $scope.Categories = null;

        categoryService.GetCategories().then(function (d) {
            $scope.Categories = "Service: " + d.data + ", Controller: categoryController";

            alert(d.data); //Here it alert [Object][Object]
        }, function () {
            alert('Failed');
        });
    }

    function categoryService($http) {
        var factory = {};

        factory.GetCategories = function () {
            return $http.get('/Product/GetCategories');
        }
        return factory;
    };
})();
```

**In the view**:

```
<div ng-app="productApp" ng-controller="categoryController">
  <select ng-model="saveProducts.ParentId">
    <option value="">----Please Select Category----</option>
    <option ng-repeat="m in Categories" value="{{ m.CategoryId }}">{{ m.Category }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you are doing categoryController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Products']; instead of categoryController.$inject = ['$scope', 'categoryService'] ?

Comment: Seems like a typo ;)

Comment: I tried that @guramidev but didn't work. Any better way?

Comment: if your just missing the alert object part you can do ```angular.toJson(d.data);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user8512043 Here is a JSFiddle with the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/2fvwz6wp/

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('productApp', [])
        .controller('categoryController', categoryController)
        .factory('categoryService', categoryService);

    categoryController.$inject = ['$scope', 'categoryService'];

    function categoryController($scope, categoryService) {
        $scope.Categories = null;

        categoryService.GetCategories().then(function (d) {
            $scope.Categories = d.data;
        }, function () {
            alert('Failed');
        });
    }

    function categoryService($http, $q) {
        var factory = {};

        factory.GetCategories = function () {
            //return $http.get('/Product/GetCategories');
            return $q.when({ data: [
              { CategoryId: 1, Category: "Category 1" },
              { CategoryId: 10, Category: "Category 2" },
              { CategoryId: 20, Category: "Category 3" }
            ]});
        }
        return factory;
    };
})();
```

Note that it looks like code was fine. The drop down wasn't working because you assigned a string to the scope variable instead of an array.

One technique to resolve issue like that is to make it as visual as you can. For example use an ng-repeat on a  instead of an .

Also in general if you are going to ask for help on StackOverflow you are going to get a lot more responses if you create a JSFiddle or Plnkr with your sample code.

Finally if you are going to do that mock the server calls. This will allow the person who wants to answer to do some quick experiments.

Comment: That's great @Luis Perez. I'll try my best to do as you advised. Thanks a lot for your sample and will be trying, then let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('productApp',[])
    .controller('categoryController', categoryController)
    .controller('productController', productController)
    .factory('categoryService', categoryService);

function categoryController($scope, categoryService) {
    $scope.data = "Service: "+categoryService.serviceName+", Controller: categoryController";
};

function productController($scope, categoryService) {
    $scope.data = "Service: "+categoryService.serviceName+", Controller: productController";
};

function categoryService() {
    return {serviceName: "categoryService"};
};})();
```

Comment: I've tried your code @Sugat Shakya and it worked partially. See my updated post if you can help on it.